# How can I bind a set/collection of complex types with Vaadin (FieldGroup) binding?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

How can I get the FieldGroup / BeanFieldGroup to bind collections of items?

Imagine there is a Book, with a set Chapters which are complex types.

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private Set<Chapter> chapters;
}

public class Chapter {
    private String Text;
    private int number;
}
```

Then for the Vaadin Layout they are being bound to e.g. a VerticalLayout (for example). How can I get the strongly typed set/collection of "chapters" to be bound?

```
public class BookLayout extends VerticalLayout {

    private TextField title = new TextField();
    // ?? chapters
}

public class ChapterLayout extends VerticalLayout {

    private TextField text = new TextField();
    private TextField number = new TextField();
}
```

The binding itself works fine but only for the top level "Book".

```
    Book dto = ... // Comes populated with chapters etc.

    BookLayout layout = new BookLayout();
    BeanFieldGroup<Book> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<>(Book.class);
    binder.setItemDataSource(dto);
    binder.bindMemberFields(layout);
```

How is is possible to bind the set of complex types? I've only found an example with a single (complex type) field.

Comment: Can you give us more information about your problem, Why do you need to bind set Set of chapters? What are the operation that you have to do on this objects?

Comment: I'm trying to create an editable form similar to the webinar example, which has a set of complex types in my case not just a single value like Address in the example (e.g. a Set of addresses). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aq_OXCVqvFI

Answer (score 4):

You can compose your own field for how you want to handle this in your UI with the [`CustomField`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.5.1/com/vaadin/ui/CustomField.html):

> A Field whose UI content can be constructed by the user, enabling the creation of e.g. form fields by composing Vaadin components. Customization of both the visual presentation and the logic of the field is possible. Subclasses must implement `AbstractField.getType()` and `initContent()`. Most custom fields can simply compose a user interface that calls the methods `AbstractField.setInternalValue(Object)` and `AbstractField.getInternalValue()` when necessary. It is also possible to override `AbstractField.validate()`, `AbstractField.setInternalValue(Object)`, `AbstractField.commit()`, `AbstractField.setPropertyDataSource(Property)`, `AbstractField.isEmpty()` and other logic of the field.

You then have to deal with binding your chapter layout for each item of set set there (e.g. put one in a container, bind it), add some add/delete functions.  Basically it's up to you then, how you implement the `CustomField<Set<Chapter>>`

Comment: I'm also using a CustomField for a similar case. Now my problem is that I got a CustomField<Set<**Entity**>>, but I don't know how to implement the AbstractField.getType() method. The function header looks like this: public Class<? extends Set<**Entity**>> getType() and my return was (Class<? extends Set<**Entity**>>) Set.class; So I can use this component but if I want to build my project in Maven I get a Compilation Error "incompatible types: "java.lang.Class<java.util.Set> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends java.util.Set<**Entity**>>". How do I solve this?

Comment: Ok, I think I found it: Class clazz = Set.class;  return (Class<? extends Set<Entity>>)clazz;